# Properly using Django Class Based View Mixins to generate PDF's

Tags: django-views, pdf-generation, django-class-based-views, weasyprint

I'm running into a roadblock whilst trying to render classed based views in an HTML template (w/ CSS & JS) to PDF using the [django-weasyprint](https://github.com/fdemmer/django-weasyprint) in the browser. The package provides Mixins for Views that can be used as described in the [README.md](https://github.com/fdemmer/django-weasyprint/blob/master/README.rst) but when I do this with my models it refuses to load in as a PDF in the browser (Chrome or Firefox). Toggling `pdf_attachment` the browser loads a regular view on False. Here are my views.py and urls.py.

views.py

```
class SampleQuoteRecipeView(DetailView):
    model = LabSample
    template_name='pdf/quote_recipe.html'
    response_class = WeasyTemplateResponse

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        query = LabSample.objects.filter(lab_sample_number=kwargs['lab_sample_number'])
        data = query.values()
        context = {}
        context.update(data[0])
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

class SampleQuotePDFView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, SampleQuoteRecipeView):
    response_class = WeasyTemplateResponse
    content_type = CONTENT_TYPE_PDF
    pdf_stylesheets = [
        settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/themes/customred/css/screen.css',
    ]
    pdf_attachment = False
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import SampleQuoteRecipeView, SampleQuotePDFView

urlpatterns = [
    path('quote/<int:lab_sample_number>/pdf', SampleQuotePDFView.as_view(template_name='pdf/quote_recipe.html')),
    path('quote/<int:lab_sample_number>', SampleQuoteRecipeView.as_view(template_name='pdf/quote_recipe.html'))
]
```

If anyone could guide me in the correct direction I'd be forever great-full. Currently the only thing I have to go on is pouring over CBV docs and tutorials on Mixins and this warning message from weasyprints:

```
**/lib/python3.5/site-packages/weasyprint/document.py:36: UserWarning: There are known rendering problems and missing features with cairo < 1.15.4. WeasyPrint may work with older versions, but please read the note about the needed cairo version on the "Install" page of the documentation before reporting bugs. http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
  'There are known rendering problems and missing features with '
```

Answer (score 0):

I have django-weasyprint working with similar code. I'd check the [Weasyprint installation docs](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing) and confirm all the dependencies are installed.

From the warning message, it looks like Cairo may not be properly installed. The docs have solid details for each linux, osx, and windows.